# SDWebImage sending unknown exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, sdwebimage

i have implemented and installed the framework correctly which it took me days, and also im new to this, the thing is i have this images from the web so i parsed it and then want to load those images using SDImageView, but after compiling im having this exception

```
-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75b9730
[2456:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75b9730'
```

when i remove the placeholder value this exception appear

```
-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7555960
[2236:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7555960'
```

my code also goes like this:

```
NSString *imageLink = [currentData imageLinkFromWeb];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageLink]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
```

Comment: Did you add `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`? Do you get build warnings? How do you know `have implemented and installed the framework correctly` when it crashes?

Comment: Looks like you have missed some thing while configuring SDWebImage. Reference to the SDWebImage is missing.

Comment: well i follwed an intruction http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html on that page and did all the things it says. but at the end im having exception and yes i also added the #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too.  For me it was caused by not adding the -ObjC linker flag to the build settings.  Instructions for adding the flag are [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#add-linker-flag).  Good luck!